# Get data from iFrame URL on every page within the iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

**Scenario**

I'm using same URL for iFrame source and Website.

The main URL is: https://www.disciplinexgames.com/beta/index

In iFrame it is : `< iframe src="https://www.disciplinexgames.com/beta/index?key=YW41y7o0ejxWVVWv7tGOv1eZMdsdew&an=pactpro&uname=mark@example.com&web=www.pactpro.net">< /iframe>`

Iframe is for our partners who want to offer our service on there own website, in this case http://www.pactpro.net. Main URL is for our own User to browse through the platform.

So the code as in front-end and backend is same for both, in iFrame we just changes the logo, name, background colour, etc , which our partner has provided.

**Problem**

Problem is that first time when the iFrame loads I'm able to get the below from the URL using `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`. But when user go into other pages within iFrame than `$_GET['key']` returns blank, hence it's not able to fetch the data from URL.

```
key=YW41y7o0ejxWVVWv7tGOv1eZMdsdew
an=pactpro
uname=mark@example.com
web=www.pactpro.net
```

Is it possible to Get the data on every page from the **iFrame src** as we're getting first time. The iFrame source remains always the same but when it comes to get the Data from iFrame source, it return blank.

I'll really appreciate your your guidance in this.

Comment: which framework or CMS do you use ?

Comment: Are you handling `$_GET` variables to compute the URLs? If you're not getting them on subsequent requests I bet that you're not adding them to hyperlinks.

Comment: It's not related your problem, but you have an unwanted output befor anything, if you see your source code: `AN=> <br />http://www.disciplinexgames.com/beta/index` And you are define your `<styles>` out of the `</html>`. So there are a lot of invalid things in your HTML. Just FYI.

Comment: @MohammadAlabed I'm using class based PHP

Comment: @lolka_bolka I'm printing those just to test it, otherwise I won't be putting them before doctype.

Comment: @colourtheweb I think if you save this variables in the session in the first visiting (maybe when someone visit the home page) and then write small script inside the theme file to test the session and get this variables

Comment: @PauloASilva can you give me an example. It's not 100% clear to me, what you saying. Thanks!

Comment: @colourtheweb If `http://example.com/?var=value` is your start URL for iframes and inside the page you have a hyperlink to `http://example.com/other.php` it must be aware of URL variables which must be persisted. So you must compute the URLs such as inside the iframe it will be `http://example.com/other.php?var=value`. You can do this using a helper function like `echo hyperlink($url, $persist, $source)` where `$url` is the base URL (string), `$persist` is an array of URL variables name to persist and `$source` will be your `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my comment, have a look at this function

```
<?php
function hyperlink($url, Array $persist, Array $source) {
    $variables = array();

    foreach ($persist as $key)
    {   
        if (isset($source[$key]))
        {       
            $variables[$key] = $source[$key];
        }       

    }   

    return $url.'?'.http_build_query($variables);
}
```

On your templates, everytime you want to output an URL you must do it like

```
<?php echo hyperlink('http://example.com', $iframe_vars, $_GET); ?>
```

Where `$iframe_vars` must be an array with the name of the variables you use with iframes and must be persisted across requests

```
<?php
$iframe_vars = array('key','an','uname','web');
```

Answer (score -1):

The website in iframe must set a cookie when it sees your $GET parameter and check the cookie on next requests

**EDIT:**

You can also use javascript to change all links to add your key if site is in an iframe.

```
if (window!=window.top){
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    [].forEach.call(list, function(el){
        el.href += el.href.indexOf('?')>0 ? '&key=yourKey' : '?key=yourKey';
    });
}
```

Comment: In iframe instead of cookie I did tried it with Session and local storage. I assigned the first time $_GET data to the session and that worked great for iframe but when you browse  http://www.disciplinexgames.com/beta/index directly then you see the logo of partner because the domain and directory is same so the SESSION continues there also. Whereas what I want is on visiting directly display the logo, etc of DisciplineXgames only.

Comment: Cookies/Session are not required or recommended